Why disabled DatePicker raise error with minDate rule?
In laravel 11 /  filamentphp 3.2  app I have DatePicker which has conditional disabled property
DatePicker::make('applied_from')
    ->required()
    ->timezone(ConfigValueEnum::get(ConfigValueEnum::TIMEZONE))
    ->native(false)
    ->format(ConfigValueEnum::get(ConfigValueEnum::DATE_ASTEXT_FORMAT))
    ->minDate(now()->startOfDay())
    ->hint('On this date approved document is in action')
    ->disabled(fn(?Doc $record) => ($record->status !== DocStatusEnum::WAITING_FOR_APPROVE)),

and when this DatePicker is disabled on validation rule :
->minDate(now()->startOfDay())

Error is raised with old date:
The applied from must be a date after or equal to 2024-09-03 00:00:00.


I suppose that disabled DatePicker must not not be saved ? Why error ?
How to show custom format for this validation error ?


You have to use sometimes in order to Validate When Present

Thank you! Looks like I need to set rule ->minDate(now()->startOfDay())   conditionally, something like
->minDate(fn(?Doc $record) => ($record->status !== DocStatusEnum::WAITING_FOR_APPROVE ? now()->startOfDay() : null))
This line did not raise error, but did not work... How correctly ?

@mstdmstd , is the solution you mentioned is not working at all or sometimesit is not working ? Please clarify.

That was my proposition what I would like to have. It does not work. But also this line did not raise any syntax error...
